# How do I mount encrypted root LVM volumes for editing or recovery?

Tags: boot, filesystem, encryption

I needed to move the /home directory on the boot/root drive to another disk to free up space.

This meant replicating the data to the other drive, then mounting the encrypted boot drive offline so I could clean out the /home dir.

Booting into single user mode to perform this task isn't an option because the root '/' dir is mounted read-only and remounting it read-write is not allowed.

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Boot using separate media such as the Elementary OS installer's
  "Try Elementary OS" option
- Unlock the root partition: `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 root_crypt`
- Verify the LVM group name - it should be 'elementary-vg': `vgscan`
- Activate the volume: `vgchange -ay elementary-vg`
- Mount the decrypted, activated LVM volume: `mount /dev/mapper/elementary--vg-root /mnt/`
- Work with files as needed